Why Spark BUG: mode PERMISSIVE not working
Anyone know why the mode PERMISSIVE is not working with Spark? I'm trying to read an excel file, and everything is correct:
schema = StructType([StructField('Col 1', StringType(), True), \
        StructField('Col 2', DoubleType(), True), \
        StructField('Col 3', DoubleType(), True), \ --------- THIS COLUMN CONTAINS BAD DATA
        StructField('column_with_bad_data', StringType(), True) --------- LETS STORE THE BAD DATA IN HERE
        ])

df = (
                            spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")
                            .option("header", True)
                            .option("dataAddress", "Sheet!A1")
                            .schema(schema)
                            .option("mode", "PERMISSIVE")   
                            .option("enforceSchema", True)   
                            .option("columnNameOfCorruptRecord", "column_with_bad_data")
                            .load("file.xlsx")
                        )

But unfortunately, I cannot see the dataframe as it throws an error:
java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: column_with_bad_data
I already tried a lot of options, already tried cache, I dont know what else to do!!! Help!
The column "column_with_bad_data" should store the bad data, and MODE: PERMISSIVE should not remove the bad data.
